# Add a page to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to add a page to SSRS report, which can be toggle on/off based on a radio button selection.

The reason I want to add a page is so I can add additional report logic information for the functional users.  Is it possible to add a page (with several text boxes) in SSRS report and show/hide based on parameter value?

> NOTE:*  One approach I could use is to add a rectangle and control its visibility via parameter.  However, when hidden, it leaves a blank space behind.  Is there a way to get rid of this blank space?

Comment: Why not just use a list control for this? you can hide or show it as you need. There is a good video tutorial for this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8EidVXasYg

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a table component. Add a detail row and a footer row and set the dataset to read from SELECT 1=1. You can put a rectangle in the rows and build out your report in the first row and then optionally show/hide the footer row.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you're saying I can add a new row in my existing table and then add rectangle in it.  I already tried this and an issue I am having is that when hidden the report will display lesser rows of data per page even when "ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace" = True.

Comment: If you hide the row of the table and not the Rectangle then it should work. The Table is dynamic in height whereas the Rectangle is not.

Comment: I added a new row and widened the row to several inches.  After setting visibility to "Hide", I am still noticing the report displaying lesser rows per page than before.  Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Let me get back to an old project of mine later this evening. I am sure I had two rows, each set to page height and was able to show either one or two pages.